# De-activating a Dashboard's running user removes all the Dashboard Filters. Can I recover?

Tags: dashboard, filters

You know how when you're editing a Dashboard, there's a "View Dashboard As: " field on the top right of the page?

Well, for several of our dashboards a previous admin had created, she had been listed as the View Dashboard as person. Naturally, when I de-activated her as a user, viewing the dashboard returned an error until I changed the "View Dashboard As: " to an active user.

What I've noticed, however, is that upon changing **all the values for the custom dashboard filters we had created just disappeared!**

The filter fields themselves are still there. So, for example, the custom Date filter on my opportunity dashboard is there, but the dozen actual values ("Next quarter", "last year", etc) have all vanished.

Is this deliberate, or should I be reporting this behavior to SF? Also, Is there a way I can recover these filter values without having to go through and repopulate them all?

Comment: Since there haven't been any responses I've just submitted this as an issue to Salesforce Support. I'll report back if there's a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this is a [known issue.](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T3GvAAK) If you experienced this problem add yourself to the 'This issue affects me' list so SF eventually gets around to fixing this bug!

The 'workaround', as detailed on that linked page, is to not deactivate the running user of the dashboards **until after** you go and change the running user in those dashboards.

If you already deactivated the user, but haven't yet changed the running user of a dashboard, you should re-activate the user, *then* change the running user over to an active user. If the current running user is inactive when you change the running user, then you WILL lose your dashboard filters, as I learned the hard way.

(Hooray for Salesforce bugs that cause hours of work to just disappear!)